# Need to create a github release on every push in Github repository

Tags: jenkins, github, release

I have to configure a Jenkins job, to create a release(in github) on every push on github. Any directions for that will be appreciated..

I have configured a Jenkins job with "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" and other Git related configurations, but don't know what will be the "Execute shell" command in "Build" section

Answer (score 0):

You could run a curl command to hit the Github API (api.github.com) in the "Execute shell" section. You would want to include all of the inputs listed below in your curl data.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release